# Connecting SQL92 datasource directly from Browser

Tags: javascript, database

Is there any way to connect directly from a browser (using a JS library) to any sql-92 supported databases without using any kind of server-side scripts?

Comment: No. If you explained what the problem you are trying to solve maybe you could get a more a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js is not browser javascript. There are many parts of it that use OS features not available in a browser context.

Even if you run a nodejs server behind the browser, it will be a big lack of security.

Comment: Is it possible to run node.js in the clients' browsers?

Comment: I believe with certain limitations. Here is guy doing it: https://blog.cloudboost.io/how-to-run-node-js-apps-in-the-browser-3f077f34f8a5